# Generating a dynamic nested JSON using for loop in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, dynamically-generated

I am newbie in Python. I have some difficulties generating a nested JSON using for loop in python. For generating a nested JSON, I got the length of dictionary on runtime and based on the dictionary length I want to generate nested JSON. eg. I got the length of dictionary is 4. The dictionary length may vary. Here is my data_dict dictionary:

```
data_dict = {"PHOTO_1" : {"key1" : "PHOTO_2", "key2" : "PHOTO_3", "key3" : "PHOTO_4"}, "PHOTO_2" : {"key1" : "PHOTO_1", "key2" : "PHOTO_3"},"PHOTO_3" : {"key1" : "PHOTO_2"},"PHOTO_4" : {"key1" : "PHOTO_1", "key2" : "PHOTO_2", "key3" : "PHOTO_3"}}
```

Expected result :

```
{
    "Requests": [
        {
            "photo": {
                "photoId": {
                    "id": "PHOTO_1"
                },
                "connections": {
                    "target": {
                        "id": "PHOTO_2"
                    }
                }
            },
            "updateData": "connections"
        },
        {
            "photo": {
                "photoId": {
                    "id": "PHOTO_1"
                },
                "connections": {

                    "target": {
                        "id": "PHOTO_3"
                    }
                }
            },
            "updateData": "connections"
        },
        {
            "photo": {
                "photoId": {
                    "id": "PHOTO_1"
                },
                "connections": {

                    "target": {
                        "id": "PHOTO_4"
                    }
                }
            },
            "updateData": "connections"
        },
        {
            "photo": {
                "photoId": {
                    "id": "PHOTO_2"
                },
                "connections": {

                    "target": {
                        "id": "PHOTO_1"
                    },
                }
            },
            "updateData": "connections"
        },
        {
            "photo": {
                "photoId": {
                    "id": "PHOTO_2"
                },
                "connections": {

                    "target": {
                        "id": "PHOTO_3"
                    },
                }
            },
            "updateData": "connections"
        },
        {
            "photo": {
                "photoId": {
                    "id": "PHOTO_3"
                },
                "connections": {

                    "target": {
                        "id": "PHOTO_2"
                    },
                }
            },
            "updateData": "connections"
        },
        {
            "photo": {
                "photoId": {
                    "id": "PHOTO_4"
                },
                "connections": {

                    "target": {
                        "id": "PHOTO_1"
                    },
                }
            },
            "updateData": "connections"
        },
        {
            "photo": {
                "photoId": {
                    "id": "PHOTO_4"
                },
                "connections": {

                    "target": {
                        "id": "PHOTO_2"
                    },
                }
            },
            "updateData": "connections"
        },
        {
            "photo": {
                "photoId": {
                    "id": "PHOTO_4"
                },
                "connections": {

                    "target": {
                        "id": "PHOTO_3"
                    },
                }
            },
            "updateData": "connections"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help. I'm not getting how to solve this query? Please don't mark it duplicate. I have already checked all the answers and my JSON query is totally different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating json in python for app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872144/generating-json-in-python-for-app-engine)

Comment: has the dictionary always length `3`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No, the dictionary length has not fixed. It is vary.

Comment: your json is invalid, you can't have same `target` keys

Comment: @ArunaRajput, you got my solution

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest hey I got your solution but I have edited my dictionary and JSON structure. Please Can you update your answer?

Comment: @ArunaRajput, added additional approach. You may check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using [*itertools.permutations()*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) function:

```
import itertools, json

data_dict = {"first_photo" : "PHOTO_1", "second_photo" : "PHOTO_2", "Thrid" : "PHOTO_3"}
result = {"Requests":[]}

for pair in sorted(itertools.permutations(data_dict.values(), 2)):
    result["Requests"].append({"photo":{"photoId":{"id": pair[0]},
                                        "connections":{"target":{"id": pair[1]}}},"updateData": "connections"})

print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

---

The additional approach for the new input dict:

```
data_dict = {"PHOTO_1" : {"key1" : "PHOTO_2", "key2" : "PHOTO_3", "key3" : "PHOTO_4"}, "PHOTO_2" : {"key1" : "PHOTO_1", "key2" : "PHOTO_3"},"PHOTO_3" : {"key1" : "PHOTO_2"},"PHOTO_4" : {"key1" : "PHOTO_1", "key2" : "PHOTO_2", "key3" : "PHOTO_3"}}
result = {"Requests":[]}

for k,d in sorted(data_dict.items()):
    for v in sorted(d.values()):
        result["Requests"].append({"photo":{"photoId":{"id": k},
                                        "connections":{"target":{"id": v}}},"updateData": "connections"})

print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```